# Some punctuation characters are not matched with Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag enabled

Tags: java, regex, unicode, pattern-matching, java-8

I have an issue with matching some of punctuation characters when Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag is enabled.

For sample code is as follows:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
final Matcher matcher = p.matcher("+");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

The output is false, although it is explicitly stated in documentation that p{Punct} includes characters such as !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

Apart from '+' sign, the same problem occurs for following characters $+<=>^`|~

When Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS is removed, it works fine

I will appreciate any hints on that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc states what comes under //p{punc}  with the caveat that
**POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)**

If you take a look at the punctuation chars in unicode there is no + or $. Take a look at the punctuation chars in unicode at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm .

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS):

> When this flag is specified then the (US-ASCII only) Predefined
>   character classes and POSIX character classes are in conformance with
>   [Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression Annex
>   C](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/): Compatibility Properties.

If you take a look at the general category property for [UTS35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#UTS35) (Unicode Technical Standard), you'll see a distinction between symbols (`S` and sub-categories) and punctuation (`P` and sub-categories) in a [table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#RL1.2a) under **General Category Property**.

Quoting:

> The most basic overall character property is the General Category,
>   which is a basic categorization of Unicode characters into: Letters,
>   Punctuation, Symbols, Marks, Numbers, Separators, and Other.

If you try your example with `\\p{S}`, with the flag on, it will match.

My guess is that `+` is not listed under punctuation as an arbitrary (yet semantically appropriate) choice, i.e. literally punctuation != symbols.